# ¿Cómo se puede dejar marcada la página en la que me encuentro en menú de navegación?

Tags: javascript, html

en mi página tengo un menú de navegación, mi duda es que puedo hacer para que me deje marcada la opción de la página donde me encuentro?

Este es mi código .html:

```
<nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
                <ul>
                    <li id="tab-index"><a href="/">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li id="tab-conocenos"><a href="sobre-nosotros">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
                    <li class="drop-down" id="tab-certificacion"><a href="#">Certificación de sistemas de gestión</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li id="tab-iso9001"><a href="iso9001-2015">ISO 9001:2015</a></li>
                            <li id="tab-iso14001"><a href="iso14001-2015">ISO 14001:2015</a></li>
                            <li id="tab-iso45001"><a href="iso45001-2018">ISO 45001:2018</a></li>
                            <li id="tab-iso27001"><a href="iso-IEC-27001">ISO/IEC 27001:2013</a></li>
                            <li id="tab-iso37001"><a href="iso37001-2016">ISO 37001:2016</a></li>
                            <li id="tab-iso28000"><a href="iso28000-2007">ISO 28000:2007</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="tab-proceso"><a href="proceso-certificacion">Proceso de Certificación</a></li>
                    <li id="tab-politicas"><a href="QFSpoliticas">QFS Políticas</a></li>
                    <li id="tab-contactanos"><a href="contactanos">Contáctanos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://qfscerts.com/client.html">Clientes</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

los `<a href>` no tienen extensión .html o .php porque uso .htacess

Código js:

```
    let url = window.location.href;

    
    const tabs = ["index", "conocenos", "certificacion", "iso9001", "iso14001", "iso45001", "iso27001", "iso37001", "iso28000", "proceso", "politicas", "contactanos"];

    tabs.forEach(e => {
        
        if (url.indexOf(e + ".php") !== -1) {
            /// Agregar tab- para hacer que coincida la Id
            setActive("tab-" + e);
        }

    });

   
    function setActive(index) {
        document.getElementById(index).setAttribute("class", "nav-item active");
    }
```

Y aunque me  dirija a la página por ejemplo `Sobre nosotros` sigue marcada la opción de Inicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En tus `href` no incluyes la extensión `php`

Comment: Estoy usando .htaccess para ocultar las extensiones en las URL, y vi que desde los `href` tambien se quitaba la extensión

Comment: ¿Cuál es la dirección completa, por ejemplo, de la página "sobre nosotros"?

Comment: sobre-nosotros.html
Todas son .html, excepto la de contactanos, esa tiene extension .php : `contactanos.php`

Comment: `tab-conocenos` no coincide con `sobre-nosotros`, ese no lo vas a poder activar.